# Prove: If $A$ and $B$ are closed subsets of $[0,\Omega]$ then at least $A$ or $B$ is bounded

Tags: general-topology, proof-writing, proof-explanation, ordinals, order-topology

As usual, I am self studying topology and my knowledge of ordinals is meagre. Have
done some research on it.

**Theorem 5.1** Any countable subset of $[0,\Omega)$ is bounded above.

(This exercise requires a knowledge of ordinals) From problems:

1)A countable space need not be compact

2)countable compact space is pseudocompact

it is immediate that the the space of countable ordinals is pseudocompact.
In fact, it actually more than just pseudocompact. In fact, it is actually more
than just pseudocompact because a continuous real valued function on $[0,\Omega)$ is ultimately constant ,so is more than just bounded. (A function $f$ on $[0, \Omega)$ if there is an ordinal number $a\in [0,\Omega)$ such that $f(x)=f(y)$ $\forall x,y\in(a, \Omega)$.) Showing that every continuous real valued function on [0, $\Omega$) is ultimately continuous is not easy. Use the following out  which is adapted from chapter 5 and 6 of Gillman and Jerison[6]

Below is part(a) of a four part question adapted from the
above text.

(a) **Claim** If A and B are closed sets of $[0,\Omega)$, then atleast A or B is bounded.

**Attempted proof**

Let A and B  be closed subsets of
$[0,\Omega)$ Then there is an ordinal number $a<\Omega$ such that $A \in [0,a]$ or $B\in [0,a]$. Since $A$ and $B$
are infinite, it contains a cluster
point. So A or B is countably compact
So by Theorem 5.1 is bounded.

I think my first effort sucks.
On second thought, I thought of
following something like this argument
[closed intervals of $\omega_1$ are compact](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/102169/) to do it.

Any help to solve this theorem would be appreciated.

Comment: What is $\Omega$? the first uncountable ordinal?

Comment: Are you also assuming $A$ and $B$ are disjoint? This is false without disjointness, for example, if both $A$ and $B$ are all of $[0, \omega_1)$.

Comment: Yup the first uncountable.assume disjointedness

Comment: @DavidLui Yes he follows Munkres (who follows Cantor): $\Omega$ is the set of all countable ordinals aka $\omega_1$ and denoted $[0,\omega_1)$ as well.

Comment: Does A or B contain cluster point?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If **both** $A$ and $B$ are (closed and) unbounded pick $a_0 \in A$ and $b_0 \in B$ with $a_0 < b_0$, and next $a_1 \in A$ with $a_1 > b_0$ and so on till we have interspersed sequences $a_0 < a_1 < a_2 < \ldots$ in $A$ and $b_0 < b_1 < b_2 < \ldots$ in $B$ with $a_n < b_n$ for all $n$. Then define $\alpha=\sup_n a_n \in [0,\Omega)$ and also $\beta=\sup_n b_n \in [0,\Omega)$ and by closedness of $A$ and $B$ (and the intersepresedness) we have $\alpha=\beta\in A \cap B$ contradicting their disjointness.

We only need that a sequence of countable ordinals has a sup that is still a countable ordinal.

It's easy that $X=[0,\Omega)$ is countably compact, just use sup argument for a countable subset of $X$ and it's clear that $X$ is not compact, as all initial segements for a cover without a finite (or even countable) subcover.

Pseudocompactness follows from countable compactness and needs no separate argument.